# How to add modal custom UIView on top of everything

Tags: ios5, ios6, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple `UIViewController` and a `UIButton` on it. I would like that when pressing the button a custom `UIView` I created (using `XIB`) will be added in a modal way so no other control or button under could be pressed.

currently I do:

```
VODPopup *popup = [[VODPopup alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 95, 200, 150)   pickerData:vodEpisodesPickerData];

popup.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:popup];
```

Which adds to `UIView` instance as a subview to my ViewController, *BUT* all other buttons located outside the `UIVIew` are pressable.

any idea??

Comment: I think what you should do is segue to a popover ViewController, not try to make a modal UIView.

Comment: I will take a look how to create segue programatically.

Comment: Thinking about it again, Segue makes transition between 2 ViewControllers and not between ViewController and UIView.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm saying; the simpler thing seems to be to use a second ViewController to host your modal UIView.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exactly behaviour, you can use UIWindow:

```
    UIWindow *overlayWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    overlayWindow.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    overlayWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.f alpha:0.f];
    overlayWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
    [overlayWindow setHidden:FALSE];
```

But you should set strong pointer for effect if you using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at several posts the nicest solution was creating a transparent UIViewController and on top I put my UIView and created a Modal Segue the when invoked it take control of everything allows only interaction with it and not with what's beneath.

This link will probably solve your problem :-)

https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/popupDemo